# ¿Cómo hago para que el resultado de ganados no me de 0?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando imprimir un gráfico con los datos que tengo en excel, pero cuando le doy a correr me da que tengo 0 ganados y 5 perdidos. El excel cuenta con 8 ganados y 5 perdidos. Esta es la función que he definido para ello, pero sólo me imprime los datos de perdidos. Me podrías decir donde esta el error en mi código.

Muchas gracias!

```
    max_row = ws.max_row
    ganado = 0
    perdido = 0
    for name in range(1, max_row + 1):
        print(ws[name][0].value)
        print(ws[name][1].value)
        print('-----')
        if ws[name][1] == 'GANADO':
            print('Win')
            ganado += 1
            print(f'Hay {ganado} ganados')
        if ws[name][1].value == 'PERDIDO':
            print('Loss')
            perdido += 1
            print(f'Hay {perdido} perdidos')
    print(f'Hay {ganado}  ganados y {perdido} perdido')

    x = ['Ganado', 'perdido']
    y = [1, 15]
    grafico.bar(x, y)
    grafico.show()
```

Comment: Sería más conveniente un `elif ws[name][1].value == 'PERDIDO':`, ya que es una opción excluyente de la anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se cual es tu error.

Esta en esta linea de codigo:

```
if ws[name][1] == 'GANADO':
```

Lo que estas haciendo ahi es comparar un objeto de la celda con una cadena de texto, entonces siempre si o si sera falso por lo tanto nunca pasara a lo que esta dentro del if.

Para eso deberias utilizar el metodo value quedando asi:

```
if ws[name][1].value == 'GANADO':
```

Al igual que lo haces mas abajo cuando es perdido.

```
 if ws[name][1].value == 'PERDIDO':
```

Ahi me comentas cualquier cosa. Saludos!

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!